# How to reverse a json file?

Tags: json

I want to reverse a JSON file ( with php, python, java or other solutions :) )

From :

```
{
 "name 1" : "value 1",
 "name 2" : "value 2"
}
```

To :

```
{
 "value 1" : "name 1",
 "value 2" : "name 2"
}
```

Ideas ? :)

Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

$str=<<<EOT
{
 "name 1" : "value 1",
 "name 2" : "value 2"
}
EOT;

echo json_encode(array_flip(json_decode($str,true)));

?>
```

---

Output: `{"value 1":"name 1","value 2":"name 2"}`